# User info improperly styled on user profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, profile-page

This is your user profile:
[image: Normal profile]

This is your user profile on UX:
[image: Profile shifted over to the right]

Any questions?

This started happening today/yesterday best I can tell, the profile page on UX has been fine for months but suddenly shifted over and got messed up. Happens when you're logged in or out, on your own profile and other people's profiles.

Apparently this also happens on Mi Yodeya and English, and sometimes on The Workplace.

Comment: I'm seeing this too - and not just on my own profile

Comment: Yup. Only seems to be UX.SE (and this Meta site too) that it's happening on, from what I have seen in my brief investigationing.

Comment: I'm seeing this on EL&U, Mi Yodeya, and -- oddly -- for some but not all users on The Workplace.  (Also here.)  Just started in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @MonicaCellio really? That's odd...I figured it it was fine on one Beta theme (cogsci) it would be fine for the rest

Comment: Further info: if I drop my browser font size three notches it goes back to the old style, but I can't read micro-text.  Sounds like a hard-coded assumption about font size and/or browser width changed?

Comment: Other beta sites where it's happening to me: music, writers, boardgames, hermeneutics.

Comment: @MonicaCellio the plot thickens...I can't repro on mi yodeya or English

Comment: @BenBrocka, what happens if you bump your fonts up?  Is your browser window narrower than the size the SE design assumes (I think that's 1024px)?  These might or might not be factors.

Comment: @MonicaCellio stays the same at all zoom levels except on UX; it breaks out of the margins at a low zoom on UX for some reason

Comment: And thicker still: this is the only user on a beta site so far where it *doesn't* happen to me.  What's special about Mr. Frustrated?  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/155/frustratedwithformsdesigner

Comment: @MonicaCellio does it happen with [Rarity](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/42/rarity)? Works for me there and on all other profiles on Work

Comment: It happens to me with Rarity.  My browser isn't as wide as the stylesheet wants it to be, but it's not far off.  But the fonts are bumped up some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer happening on UX.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.  This is debugging info, because the comment thread is getting long.

**Update:** I observed the following on Firefox 3.6 and IE 8 (I know, corporate IT isn't up on the latest versions) on Windows XP.  I am *not* seeing this problem at home with Firefox 13 or Safari 5.1.7 on OS 10.6.  (end update)

This shifting happens to me on both beta and graduated sites, but not *universally*.  It does not happen [with this user on Workspace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/155/frustratedwithformsdesigner), but it does happen wtih [another user on the same site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/42/rarity).  It does not happen when Ben Brocka views that same user.

It happens to me with my own profile on: EL&U, Mi Yodeya, The Workspace, Music, Biblical Hermeneutics, Writers, Board and Card Games.  It was happening on UX at the time I posted this but was not doing it several hours later.  (It was still doing it on other sites, though.)

I use browser settings (Firefox ctrl-+) to increase the font sizes on these sites.  In a test on Mi Yodeya, if I reduce the font three notches (3x ctrl--) the problem goes away, but I can't read text that small.  I turned of Stylish to make sure no style overrides were causing this; no difference.  I'm not using anything else that should affect rendering on SE.

My browser window is not quite as wide as the site design wants it to be, but it's not tiny.  I was once told that the site assumes 1024px width; if so, then eyeballing, I'm probably at about 900px.

Everything I've written is about Firefox.  I just tried Rarity's Workspace profile in IE and it worked there.  The SE site design apparently does not respond to the IE font directive (Text -> Larger/Largest) and ctrl-+ zooms the entire page, not just the fonts, so I apparently can't create an equivalent situation using that browser.  (Whole-page zoom means horizontal scrolling, which is one reason I avoid IE.)

Ben's browser, browser size, and font zoom level are as yet unknown.

Finally, when I visit a page with the broken formatting, I very briefly see it with the correct formatting and then it redraws.  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Huh.  And now I am no longer seeing the problem on UX, but I am still seeing it everywhere else where I saw it before.

Comment: Still seeing it? Seems to have gone away for me

Comment: I'm no longer seeing it on UX.  I am still seeing it on the other sites I mentioned.  Very weird, but no longer UX's bug.